# How to determine Kafka topic partition offset if we haven't consumed any messages yet

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

librdkafka contains the function `rd_kafka_position` which fetches the current offsets for the given topic-partitions. But the comment says:

> ```
> The \p offset field of each requested partition will be set to the offset
> of the last consumed message + 1, or RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_INVALID in case there was
> no previous message.
> ```

In other words, it won't give you any useful information if no messages have been consumed yet.

I'm interested in the case where I've just subscribed to a topic, and I've already called `rd_kafka_seek` to either:

1. seek to a known position (in the case of error recovery), or
2. seek to the very end of the partition.

What I'd like to know, in this context, is what the offset would be for the next message *if* one were to be consumed. In other words, in the first case, it should be the same offset that was passed to `rd_kafka_seek`, and in the second case, it should be 1 plus the offset of the last message that was in the partition when `rd_kafka_seek` was called.

Unfortunately, just like the comment says, `rd_kafka_position` doesn't return this information. If no messages have been consumed yet, it gives `-1001` (`RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_INVALID`). If I consume a message and then call `rd_kafka_position`, it gives the correct offset.

Is there some other function that I can call in order to get the offset *before* consuming any messages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are after.... "offset" is something that is consumer-specific, in most cases (except for two cases I mention below). It tracks read progress of each specific consumer for each topic/partition, and if there was no reading done by that consumer yet - there is no consumer-specific offset for that topic/partition yet. So, asking for an offset of this consumer in this case does not make any sense - the consumer has not yet read anything, so there is no offset associated with it and it could be started from any offset you wish it to start.

The two main cases when consumer-unrelated offsets are useful are:

- when you know which offsets in a topic you want to start processing from based on either time of the messages or some custom
  error logging/reporting you have in your application
- or when you want to start from either EARLIEST or LATEST available offsets in the topic

If you know what position in a partition you want a consumer to start reading from - you just seek to that position and let your consumer start consuming messages from then on. And then you can track progress of this consumer by asking what offset it is at at any point in time ....

And if you want to start either from earliest or latest position - you can find out what that position is (using KAfkaAdminClient.listOffsets(), for example, in 2.5.x version - that is in Java, I don't know what is an equivalent method in Python), and then again seek to that position and start you consumer from it.

So, in brief, again, you can only expect to get a correct offset for a consumer if it has read anything from the topic; otherwise - the only consumer-unrelated meaningful information would be the earliest, latest or some specific (known) offsets determined by you

Comment: What I mean is that I want Kafka to tell me, *if* the consumer were to consume a message, what the offset of that message would be. I disagree with the idea that this does not make sense. Kafka obviously knows what that number is, otherwise, it would not be able to decide what is the next record it should send to the consumer.

Comment: Kafka does not know what that number is *until* you tell it so - by starting your consumer from a specific offset you want it to start. Once you start the consumer - then Kafka will have a record of that in it's internal offsets topic  - which means it "knows" now your consumer's position - and can tell you where your consumer is , next time

Comment: If the consumer has already called `rd_kafka_seek`, then the Kafka broker must know what offset the consumer is supposed to start consuming messages from, and there should be a way to ask Kafka to give me that information.

Comment: in other words, say at time T2 you decide to start your consumer at position 555 on some topic/partition. If you are asking Kafka what position/offset your consumer will start at, at some time T1 < T2 - Kafka has no idea, as it can't predict the future of what happens at T2 and which offset you will want your consumer to start from .... If you asking this question after T2 - Kafka knows the answer as the offsets are already tracked internally

Comment: if you stored the position (committed the offsets for your consumer) after you called the rd_kafka_seek - yes, it will know. If you did not - there is no record of that in Kafka

Comment: Are you saying that the `rd_kafka_seek` function does not actually communicate with Kafka?

Comment: I don't know the internals of the rd_kafka_seek() method - it it stores the requested offsets for the consumer as the current offset - then you are right, after that call you shoudl be able to ask for the offsets of the consumer. I suspect thought hat it might not commit the offsets as part of that call. I would check the implementation of the method to know for sure

Comment: `rd_kafka_seek` has a timeout argument, so I think that it does communicate with Kafka. So I think that my question is meaningful and ought to have an answer - even if that answer is simply, "librdkafka should support this but does not".

Answer (score 0):

committed() (C++ API) or rd_kafka_committed() (C API) retrieves the *committed* offsets of every topic/partition.  Some discussion here:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1964